# script to modify repository to new release

Tags: repository

do you use a script to modify all repository to new ubuntu release?

example, i upgrade from jammy to kinetic, exist a script to verify if exist (and do the edit ONLY IF exists) the new channel kinetic and modify the ppa? as below:

FROM:
`less oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-jammy.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

TO:
`less oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-kinetic.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/ kinetic main
```

THANKS GUYS!

Comment: It would be pretty easy to write such a script (*I'd do it if I felt I needed to*), but to me the idea is improper anyway. Ubuntu & Debian are different systems, and [*Ubuntu release upgrader* Tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) do more than that, with that approach better fitting Debian.

Comment: I agree with @guiverc as there is a reason why when you run a `do-release-upgrade` that it disables all of your 3rd party repositories that the repository itself may not be ready for the newer version of Ubuntu.  The `do-release-upgrade` will make that change to the repo line automatically for you, but it will be commented out so you can make sure that the repo is ready before you uncomment it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an automated script.  You can use what is already on the system  You can use a `sed` command to change all of the instances of `jammy` to `kinetic`.

```
sudo sed -i 's/jammy/kinetic/' *.list
```

would change all the list files that contained the word `jammy` to `kinetic` if it exists in the file that is in the directory that you are in.

If you wanted to create backups of the files in place it would be pretty much the same command.

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/jammy/kinetic/' *.list
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called *"Search and Replace"* in your text editor.

However, the real challenge is to be sure that a certain PPA has updated packages to the version of Ubuntu you're upgrading to.

You could maybe code a web scraper to find out this info, but I don't think it's feasible. So I'm afraid you have to manually check that each PPA is compatible with your desired version of Ubuntu, then remove invalid PPA's (or hold your upgrade), and finally Search and Replace the distro name in your sources list.

So does a script exist? Not to my knowledge. But I've given the details about how I believe the task should be solved.

Comment: yes i know @Artur but i ask for and automated script, and search and replace not verify if exist a new channel for the new ubuntu release

Comment: i asked for an automated script because i have 216 repository

Comment: If you find a bullet-proof way to check that 216 PPA's have a valid upgrade path to the next version of Ubuntu, I'm sure it would be interesting to someone.